# Enviar Json desde jQuery a Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, spring-mvc

Quiero enviar un Json con este formato

```
{
    "tarjetas": [
        {"nombre":nombre, "id": id, "lista": lista, "idLista": idLista},
        {"nombre":nombre, "id": id, "lista": lista, "idLista": idLista}
       ...
    ]
}
```

Lo construyo así:

```
var tarjetas  = [];
var objeto = {};

tarjetas.push({ 
        "nombre"    : arrayCards[i],
        "id"  : arrayCardsId[i],
        "nombreLista"    : nombreLista,
        "idLista": arrayCardsList[i]

    });
objeto.tarjetas = tarjetas;
```

Para ello tengo este código en Javascript con jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType : 'json',
      url: "http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/alo",
      data: JSON.stringify(objeto), 
      success :function(result) {
       // do what ever you want with data
     }
```

Código del controlador:

```
 @RequestMapping(value= "/j", method = RequestMethod.POST)

       public  String  recibe(@RequestBody Tarjetas tarjeta){

           System.out.println("Post");
           System.out.println(tarjeta.toString());
           return "index";
       }
```

Clase Tarjetas:

```
public class Tarjetas {
    private String tName;
    private String tId;
    private String nameList;
    private String idList;  
}
```

Mi problema es que no entiendo cómo recibir el Json en el controlador, para trabajar despues con los datos recibidos, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu `json` de entrada debe tener un mapeo directo a la clase que recibes con `@RequestBody`

Dado:

```
{
    "tarjetas": [ ... ]
}
```

Debes definir una clase con un atributo `tarjetas` que sea un listado (por el arreglo en el `json`):

```
public class TarjetasWrapper {
    private List tarjetas;
}
```

Cada elemento en el listado de `tarjetas` tiene un objeto `json`:

```
{"nombre":nombre, "id": id, "lista": lista, "idLista": idLista}
```

Por lo que en java el `List tarjetas` debe ser de una clase que tenga los atributos: `nombre`, `id`, `lista`, `idLista`:

```
public class Tarjetas {
    private List<Tarjeta> tarjetas;
}

public class Tarjeta {
    private String nombre;
    private String id;
    private String lista;
    private String idLista;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no entendía muy bien el mapeo de clases, pero sigue sin funcionar el controlador,  en Muchas gracias, no entendía muy bien el mapeo de clases, pero sigue sin funcionar el controlador, sólo recibo si cambio Tarjetas por String public String recibe(@RequestBody Tarjetas tarjeta){

Comment: prueba eliminar `JSON.stringify()`, pasando como `data: objeto`

Comment: Tras elimnar JSON.stringify() y content-Type consegui hacer la llamada, podría mostrar los valores recibidos así : @RequestMapping(value ="/j", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void posted(Tarjetas tarjeta) {
      System.out.println("Post");
      List t= tarjeta.getTarjetas();
   
  for( int i=0; i<t.size();i++)
  
      System.out.println("recibo "+ t.get(i)); 
      
  }